# How to set global access control in yii2?

Tags: yii2, access-control

I have `AdminController` with `behavior`:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['*'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['index', 'logout'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['admin', 'editor', 'expert'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['update', 'delete'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['get'],
            ],
        ],
    ]; 
}
```

Then i create child controllers for:

- default controller
- inf-courses controller
- and other

How can i use rules on parent (`AdminController`) then its working?
If i add similar rules in `deafult` it works, but globally not.

P.S. I do admin panel and want next:
- any one can try to login
- access to admin pane: `['admin', 'editor', 'expert']`
- logout can only `['admin', 'editor', 'expert']`

It's globally rules for all module `admin` with parent `AdminController`.

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend controller and then override `behaviors()` then you make sure to include parent's behaviors like this:

```
return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
  // your behaviors here
]);
```

Comment: You do not understand me. Look, i replaced `*` to `?` and have logic where i can not go to `default/*`. But, how can i declare same login for all controllers if i have these: `/admin/CONTROLLER/ACTION`. I need to block user for each controller and each action besides `/admin/default/login`

Comment: Hmm, now i have not working rule... Look at my answer above (big post) and for these rules for users. I do structure that you wrote and my behaviors: `'access' => [ 'rules' => [ [ 'actions' => ['update'], 'allow' => true, 'roles' => ['admin'], ], [ 'actions' => ['view', 'index'], 'allow' => true, 'roles' => ['editor', 'expert'], ], ] ],`. If i **editor** i can edit now (but should not)

Answer (score 0):

Done!
I make my AdminController like:

```
class AdminController extends Controller {

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['admin', 'editor', 'expert'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['delete'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['admin'],
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['get'],
                ],
            ],
        ]; 
    }
}
```

And extends it for each controller in admin